# Console log for foreach javascript didn't show up

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I've been trying to work on some validation in javascript, just a simple one. But, the error can't show up in the console log. If all the inputs are correct, it will show the "Registration success text" but in the other side, it won't show any of the error text. But it somehow still can get the focus function to the wrong input, only the error texts that are not showing up in the console. I am so confused. Can you guys help me? I'd appreciate that.

```
function validate(name, uname, email, passw, confpassw, region, gender, termss){
  let error = [];

  if(name.value === ''){
    error.push("Name is required.");
    name.focus();
    return false;
  } 

  if(name.value.length < 4){
    error.push("Length of name is less than 4 characters.");
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if(uname.value === ''){
    error.push("Username is required.");
    uname.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if(uname.value.length < 8 || uname.value.length > 14){
    error.push("Length of username must between 8-14 characters.");
    uname.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value === ''){
    error.push("Email is required.");
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if((email.value.indexOf('@') == -1 && email.value.indexOf('.') == -1) ||
    (!email.value.endsWith('gmail.com') && (!email.value.endsWith('gmail.co.id')))
    || email.value.indexOf('@')+1 === email.value.indexOf('.')){
    error.push("Email is not valid.");
    return false;
  } 

  if(passw.value === ''){
    error.push("Password is required.");
    passw.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if(confpassw.value === ''){
    error.push("Confirmation Password is required.");
    confpassw.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if(passw.value != confpassw.value){
    error.push("The password didn't match.");  
    passw.focus();
    confpassw.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if(region.value == 0){
    error.push("Region is not selected");
    region.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if(gender.value == 0){
    error.push("Gender is not selected");
    gender.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if(!termss.checked){
    error.push("Please agree to the terms and conditions if you want to proceed.");
    termss.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if(error.length == 0){
    alert("Registration Success!");
  } else{
    for(var i=0; i<error.length; i++){
      console.log(error.length[i]);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: when you rerun than how it will print ??

Comment: either return at the end or change the logic

Comment: it didn't print anything in the console @xdeepakv

Comment: i've tried to put some dummy print to test if the 'else' is working. but it didn't even get into the else function 2

Comment: Its returns as soon as getting any error then how it prints the console. This is what xdeepakv says.

Comment: yes, on error you are returning from function. SO console is unreachable code.

Comment: Why are you [reinventing the wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)? Always check if there's a built in way before rolling your own.

Comment: ahh i see. it can run now. thanks guys! i am kinda new into programming so it's still kind of a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning too early so it is never reaching your consoles. You are focusing on multiple fields.

```
  if(passw.value != confpassw.value){
    error.push("The password didn't match.");  
    passw.focus();
    confpassw.focus();
    return false;
  }
```

You are also doing `console.log(error.length[i]);` instead of `console.log(error[i]);`.

```
function validate(name, uname, email, passw, confpassw, region, gender, termss){
  let error = [];
  let firstFailedField = null;
  const setFirstFailedField = (field) => {
    if (!firstFailedField) firstFailedField = field;
  };

  if(name.value === ''){
    error.push("Name is required.");
    setFirstFailedField(name);
  } 

  if(name.value.length < 4){
    error.push("Length of name is less than 4 characters.");
    setFirstFailedField(name);
  }

  if(uname.value === ''){
    error.push("Username is required.");
    setFirstFailedField(uname);
  }

  if(uname.value.length < 8 || uname.value.length > 14){
    error.push("Length of username must between 8-14 characters.");
    setFirstFailedField(uname);
  }

  if(email.value === ''){
    error.push("Email is required.");
    setFirstFailedField(email);
  }

  if((email.value.indexOf('@') == -1 && email.value.indexOf('.') == -1) ||
    (!email.value.endsWith('gmail.com') && (!email.value.endsWith('gmail.co.id')))
    || email.value.indexOf('@')+1 === email.value.indexOf('.')){
    error.push("Email is not valid.");
    setFirstFailedField(email);
  } 

  if(passw.value === ''){
    error.push("Password is required.");
    setFirstFailedField(passw);
  }

  if(confpassw.value === ''){
    error.push("Confirmation Password is required.");
    setFirstFailedField(confpassw);
  }

  if(passw.value != confpassw.value){
    error.push("The password didn't match.");  
    setFirstFailedField(confpassw);
  }

  if(region.value == 0){
    error.push("Region is not selected");
    setFirstFailedField(region);
  }

  if(gender.value == 0){
    error.push("Gender is not selected");
    setFirstFailedField(gender);
  }

  if(!termss.checked){
    error.push("Please agree to the terms and conditions if you want to proceed.");
    setFirstFailedField(termss);
  }

  if(error.length == 0){
    alert("Registration Success!");
    return true;
  }
  error.forEach((err) => (console.log(err)));
  if (firstFailedField && typeof firstFailedField.focus === 'function') firstFailedField.focus();
  return false;
}
```